# Deploying Site Updates from Orchard to Azure

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I have an Orchard Site. This site is currently being deployed to Windows Azure. The initial deployment took me roughly 20 minutes. However, I'm now making some template changes. I've noticed that each time I try to promote an update to Azure, it takes between 10 and 15 minutes . Is this normal? Is there something that I am misunderstanding? In my opinion, making a minor .css change should be able to be deployed fairly quickly from Orchard to Azure.

Can somebody please help me understand how to deploy Orchard site updates to Azure more efficiently?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the Azure web role as opposed to Azure websites, correct? If so, this is normal, and there is no way around it. This is a limitation of how Azure web/worker roles are deployed.

The Azure project build outputs two artifacts: (1) a .cspkg file which is a package that gets deployed to Azure, and (2) a service definition .cscfg file that tells Azure how to configure your site; how many instances, what size instances, etc.

The .cspkg package has all your site code, .css, .js, web.config's, etc, and in order to change any of those, even a trivial .css edit, you have to redeploy that entire package. I think the package file for Orchard is around 20MB for a basic install. There is no way around this.

The only thing you can change without the lengthy redeploy is the stuff in the service configuration. You are allowed to upload updated versions of that file.

If this is unacceptable for you, you might consider switching to Azure Websites which has a more flexible deploy. You can deploy by FTP and Git, which I think will allow you to make more granular changes, and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to take around 10-15 minutes to upgrade your deployment in an Azure Hosted Service. 
If you just want to check how your changes look on published servers, connect with remote desktop on you Azure server, upload your new css files and refresh your browser !
You can even update the views of your themes or modules. But be careful, do not expect these files to stay there without upgrading your instance.